# React-Apollo throws an network error 404?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, apollo

I am new to React-apollo I just trying to figure out how to do Server side rendering with apollo and it always throws me an error 404 and I am pretty sure my 
grapiql endpoint is working.

this is my error

```
{ Error: Network error: Network request failed with status 404 - "Not Found"
    at new ApolloError (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\errors\ApolloError.js:32:28)
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:268:41
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:705:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:702:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:699:42)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:65:23)
    at dispatch (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\redux\lib\createStore.js:186:19)
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\ApolloClient.js:174:30
  graphQLErrors: [],
  networkError:
   { Error: Network request failed with status 404 - "Not Found"
       at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\transport\networkInterface.js:116:33
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
     response:
      Body {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        status: 404,
        statusText: 'Not Found',
        headers: [Object],
        ok: false,
        body: [Object],
        bodyUsed: true,
        size: 0,
        timeout: 0,
        _raw: [Object],
        _abort: false,
        _bytes: 140 },
     parseError:
      { Error
          at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\body.js:48:31
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
        name: 'FetchError',
        message: 'invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0',
        type: 'invalid-json' } },
  message: 'Network error: Network request failed with status 404 - "Not Found"',
  extraInfo: undefined,
  queryErrors: [ [Circular] ] }
```

this is my server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import path from 'path';
import expressGraphQL from 'express-graphql';
import schema from './GraphQL/Schema';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface, ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { getDataFromTree } from "react-apollo"
import store from '../client/Redux/Store/store';

require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

import WApp from '../client/App';


//Dev HMR
import HMR from './serverUtils/HMR';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', expressGraphQL({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
}));
app.use('/static',express.static('build'));
HMR(app);

function Html({ content, state }) {
    return (
        <html>
        <body>
        <div id="app"  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}/>
        <script src="/static/app.js" />
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `window.__APOLLO_STATE__=${JSON.stringify(state).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')};`,
        }} />
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}

app.get('*',(req,res) => {


     const context = {};
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: true,
        // Remember that this is the interface the SSR server will use to connect to the
        // API server, so we need to ensure it isn't firewalled, etc
        networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
            uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
            opts: {
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                // transfer request headers to networkInterface so that they're accessible to proxy server
                // Addresses this issue: https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/83
                headers: req.headers,
            },
        }),




    });


     const app = (
         <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
             <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client} >

                     <WApp/>

             </ApolloProvider>
         </StaticRouter>

     );


     getDataFromTree(app).then(() => {
         const content  = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(app);
         const initialState = {[client.reduxRootKey]: client.getInitialState()  };
         const html = <Html content={content} state={initialState} />;
         console.log('Initial State',initialState);
         res.status(200);
         res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(html)}`);
         res.end();
     }).catch(err => console.log(err))





});




app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('Man I on')
})
```

Update according to the answer

it throws me an error like this

```
{ Error: Network error: Network request failed with status 200 - "OK"
    at new ApolloError (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\errors\ApolloError.js:32:28)
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:268:41
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:705:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:702:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:699:42)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:65:23)
    at dispatch (C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\redux\lib\createStore.js:186:19)
    at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\ApolloClient.js:174:30
  graphQLErrors: [],
  networkError:
   { Error: Network request failed with status 200 - "OK"
       at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\apollo-client\src\transport\networkInterface.js:116:33
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
     response:
      Body {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        headers: [Object],
        ok: true,
        body: [Object],
        bodyUsed: true,
        size: 0,
        timeout: 0,
        _raw: [Object],
        _abort: false,
        _bytes: 37593 },
     parseError:
      { Error
          at C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folder\FinalHustleBoilerPlate\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\body.js:48:31
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
        name: 'FetchError',
        message: 'invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0',
        type: 'invalid-json' } },
  message: 'Network error: Network request failed with status 200 - "OK"',
  extraInfo: undefined,
  queryErrors: [ [Circular] ] }
```

HINT: Because of json parse error I am adding root query file I am using axios with fake data

```
import { GraphQLObjectType ,GraphQLNonNull,GraphQLID,GraphQLList} from 'graphql';
import axios from 'axios';

//All types
import PostType from './Post_Type';





const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'RootQueryType',
    fields:{
        posts:{
            type:new GraphQLList(PostType),
            resolve(parentValue,args){

                  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' )
                .then(res => res.data)
            }

        },
        post:{
            type:PostType,
            args:{ id: { type:new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
            resolve(parentValue,{id}){
                return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
            }
        }

    }
});

export default RootQueryType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  // ...
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
    // ...
  })
});
```